# Drag and drop Xamarin Forms (iOS only) objects

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Dello, I have a project in xamarin forms.
[image]
As you can see in the picture, I have drug images and buttons that contain the ingredients in the drugs.

I want to drag and drop buttons to the drug images so that I can tell the user that they are correct or wrong. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: What have you tried? UIView has touch events you can listen to and adjust x and y coordinates depending on what the user is doing on that element.

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @SreejithSree Unnecessarily too much math is required, and I did it with Flutter. In two hours, the Flutter is really good.

Comment: Could you please have a look on this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543223/xamarin-forms-how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-flowlistview-label-in-xamarin-form