# Xamarin Forms: How to implement Drag and Drop Flowlistview Label in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a fill in the blanks game on my project. I am using flowlistviews for showing items on UI.

I have 2 flowlistviews aligned vertically on my project. The top flowlistview shows the questions and bottom flowlistview has its answers. I need to drag the answer from the bottom listview and drop it on the top list view.

Also instead of `{{2fill}}` I need a blank space (underscore) on UI where the answer from bottom listview is dropping.

**Screenshot**

[image]

I have uploaded a video [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XiVzzjKxc_hvIyqmoJxMS8QfGYKhAS8A), which contains the working of this game. I need to drag the answer from the bottom list and put it on the top list blank space. If the answer is right the player gets point and if the answer is wrong, the dragged item goes back to the bottom list as per the video.

Comment: You could create a  draggable view in Xamarin Forms . Check http://www.xamboy.com/2017/08/23/draggable-view-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have implemented a draggable view and now I can drag the answers from bottom flowlistview and drop anywhere on UI. I added a converter for questions for replacing the `{{2fill}}` into ________. Now how  can I check the draggable answer is correct or not? Is there any event when put a label on top of listview item?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have created a sample project with a draggable view, can you help me to do the remaining feature, like answer matching, if the answer is right put the answer on the blank space and put back the answer if it is wrong.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wlF2RXL7QnCvjsm04D9NFhtqOlrM0SFG